# Unable to setup a Spring application main method from a demo project - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am exploring this project - https://github.com/davidmarquis/redis-scheduler.

I set it up and was able to run the integration tests there (although most of the test cases in  SpringIntegrationTest fail in that, but that's another story).

Now, I would like to run the application and not the tests.
I just added a main class in the package com.github.davidmarquis.redisscheduler; -

```
package com.github.davidmarquis.redisscheduler;


import com.github.davidmarquis.redisscheduler.drivers.jedis.JedisDriver;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool;

import java.time.Instant;

public class Main {


    static  RedisTaskScheduler scheduler;
    private static JedisPool pool;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        provideActors();

    }


    private static void provideActors() {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context-test.xml");

        scheduler = ctx.getBean(RedisTaskScheduler.class);

        ApplicationContext ctxAnno = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        pool = (JedisPool) ctxAnno.getBean("jedis");
    }

    public void stopScheduler() {
        scheduler.stop();
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        pool.close();
    }
}
```

I added the following configuration class -

```
package com.github.davidmarquis.redisscheduler;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean(name="jedis")
    public JedisPool helloWorld() {
        return new JedisPool("localhost", 6379);
    }
}
```

Here is the pom for reference (same as the github project) -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.github.davidmarquis</groupId>
    <artifactId>redis-scheduler</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>redis-scheduler</name>
    <description>Java implementation of a lightweight distributed task scheduler backed by Redis</description>
    <url>https://github.com/davidmarquis/redis-scheduler</url>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>MIT</name>
            <url>http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:davidmarquis/redis-scheduler.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:davidmarquis/redis-scheduler.git</developerConnection>
        <url>git@github.com:davidmarquis/redis-scheduler.git</url>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
    </scm>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <id>davidmarquis</id>
            <name>David Marquis</name>
            <email>david@radiant3.ca</email>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>ossrh</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
        <repository>
            <id>ossrh</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Lettuce driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
            <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jedis driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Data Redis driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.11.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.15.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.15.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Tests -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.kstyrc</groupId>
            <artifactId>embedded-redis</artifactId>
            <version>0.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
                
                
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>release</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>performRelease</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>attach-sources</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>jar</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.5</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                                <phase>verify</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>sign</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>disable-java8-doclint</id>
            <activation>
                <jdk>[1.8,)</jdk>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                    <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
                    <releaseProfiles>release</releaseProfiles>
                    <goals>deploy</goals>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.7</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
                    <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
                    <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>
    
</project>
```

I get the following exception on running the main class -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2688)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3035)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3005)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1771)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

**Update**
application-context-test.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="test-config.properties"/>

    <bean id="jedisConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory">
        <property name="hostName" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="port" value="6379"/>
        <property name="database" value="0"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jedisConnectionFactory"/>
        <property name="keySerializer">
            <bean class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="triggerListener" class="com.github.davidmarquis.redisscheduler.lib.LatchedTriggerListener"/>

    <bean id="stubbedClock" class="com.github.davidmarquis.redisscheduler.lib.StubbedClock" />

    <bean id="springTemplateDriver" class="com.github.davidmarquis.redisscheduler.drivers.spring.RedisTemplateDriver">
        <constructor-arg name="redisTemplate" ref="redisTemplate"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="scheduler" class="com.github.davidmarquis.redisscheduler.RedisTaskScheduler" >
        <constructor-arg name="driver" ref="springTemplateDriver"/>
        <!-- <constructor-arg name="listener" ref="triggerListener"/>-->
        <constructor-arg name="listener">
            <bean class="com.github.davidmarquis.redisscheduler.Implementation"/>
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="clock" ref="stubbedClock"/>
        <property name="pollingDelayMillis" value="10"/>  <!-- Speeds up polling for tests so that they run quicker. -->
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**Update 2**

I tried adding the spring-core jar to classpath, still no change -
[image]

**Update 3**

The error for this class went away when I added spring-context-4.3.15.RELEASE.jar to the classpath. But then I am getting error for another -

org.springframework.expression.ParserContext

Why am I having to do this for each and every spring component? This is such a pain!

Comment: I guess it is because `spring-core` dependency is in `provided` scope in the pom. That is why you would have to provide it for the classpath manually when running the jar. Try to get rid of the `scope` tag there and see.

Comment: removing the scope did not work. I rebuilt the project after removing - clean install. How do I provide it in classpath? I tried to follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/1051705/351903 and added the jar from my local maven repository, but still no change

Comment: @KUSH42 you mean Right click on the project, go to Maven -> Reimport? I did this too. No change